# Add 3rd party libraries to necessitas Qt project?

Tags: android

I want to add an external library to my necessitas Qt project, so I added the following line to the .pro file:

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include

LIBS += -L$$PWD/shared/libs/armeabi -lopenal

However, when I start running my application, it failed to start:

```
m( 3443): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'QtIndustrius-14.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
D/dalvikvm( 3443): DexOpt: --- END 'QtIndustrius-14.jar' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm( 3443): DEX prep '/data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/jar/QtIndustrius-14.jar': unzip in 22ms, rewrite 438ms
D/dalvikvm( 3443): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x4050e990 
D/dalvikvm( 3443): Added shared lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x4050e990 
D/dalvikvm( 3443): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x4050e990, 
skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 3443): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x4050e990 
D/dalvikvm( 3443): Added shared lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x4050e990 
D/dalvikvm( 3443): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x4050e990, 
skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 3443): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/plugins/platforms/android/ 
libandroid-9.so 0x4050e990
D/dalvikvm( 3443): Added shared lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/plugins/platforms/android/ 
libandroid-9.so 0x4050e990
I/Qt      ( 3443): qt start
D/dalvikvm( 3443): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.example.AndroidPlayer/lib/libAndroidPlayer.so 
0x4050e990
W/System.err( 3443): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/System.err( 3443):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3443):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/System.err( 3443):         at org.kde.necessitas.origo.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:144) 
W/System.err( 3443):         at org.kde.necessitas.origo.QtActivity.access $200(QtActivity.java:77)
W/System.err( 3443):         at org.kde.necessitas.origo.QtActivity $3$1$1.run(QtActivity.java:201)
W/System.err( 3443):         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/System.err( 3443):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err( 3443):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err( 3443):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
W/System.err( 3443):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3443):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 507)
W/System.err( 3443):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
W/System.err( 3443):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
W/System.err( 3443):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3443): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1962]:    33 could not load needed library
'libopenal.so' for 'libAndroidPlayer.so' (load_library[1104]: Library 'libopenal.so' not found)
W/System.err( 3443):         at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:394)
W/System.err( 3443):         at java.lang.System.load(System.java:534)
W/System.err( 3443):         at org.kde.necessitas.industrius.QtNative.loadBundledLibraries(QtNative.java: 125) 
W/System.err( 3443):         at org.kde.necessitas.industrius.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java: 245)
W/System.err( 3443):         ... 14 more
```

But when I deleted those lines and files using the external lib, my app goes fine.
I have already pushed libopenal.so to /data/local/lib, and added it to global evironment by "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/local/lib"

So how can I add 3rd party libraries to my project? And how to put them in my apk?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, click "Configure Build Path" and then "Add JAR", then select you library.